# sqlite3: my sql query runs into endless loop

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

> **id** as int, **prop** as text, **timestamp** as int, **json** as blob

I want to find all pairs, which have the same prop and with the same timestamp. Later I want to extend the timestamp to e.g., +/- 5 sec.

I try to do it with `INNER JOIN` but my query runs into endless loop:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable c 
INNER JOIN myTable c1 
     ON c.id != c1.id 
     AND c.prop = c1.prop 
     AND c.timestamp = c1.timestamp
```

Maybe my approach is wrong. What is the problem with my query? How can I do it? Actually, I need groups with these pairs.

Comment: That query should end, but may take some time...

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (And take a look at [mcve], make it easy to assist you!)

Comment: I'd probably consider a GROUP BY instead of self join.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to see if the query gets faster with a GROUP BY:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE (prop, timestamp) IN (
    SELECT prop, timestamp
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY prop, timestamp
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Although its hard to say without sample data.

If the table is huge you might have to create an index to speed up the query.